# Java 8 :: Implementing SOAP call: getting com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ClassFactory No default constructor found on class javax.activation.DataHandler

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap

I am trying to implement a SOAP web service and I have generated stub files using CXF. However, when I am trying to call the Web Service, I get an error:

> com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ClassFactory No default constructor found
>   on class javax.activation.DataHandler java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:
>   javax.activation.DataHandler.()

I looked into the XSD for the WSDL file and here is what I found:

```
<xs:complexType name="EDMSFile">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
<xs:element xmlns:ns1="http://www.w3.org/2005/05/xmlmime" name="contentAsMTOM" ns1:expectedContentTypes="application/octet-stream" type="xs:base64Binary" minOccurs="0"></xs:element>
<xs:element name="contentAsBase64" type="xs:base64Binary" minOccurs="0"></xs:element>
<xs:element name="format" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

while In the generated stub EDMSFile.java (given below), I can see that contentAsMTOM is of type DataHandler while in XSD (above) it is of type xs:base64Binary.

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "EDMSFile", propOrder = {
    "name",
    "contentAsMTOM",
    "contentAsBase64",
    "format"
})
public class EDMSFile {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String name;
    @XmlMimeType("application/octet-stream")
    protected DataHandler contentAsMTOM;
    protected byte[] contentAsBase64;
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String format;


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }


    public void setName(String value) {
        this.name = value;
    }


    public DataHandler getContentAsMTOM() {
        return contentAsMTOM;
    }


    public void setContentAsMTOM(DataHandler value) {
        this.contentAsMTOM = value;
    }


    public byte[] getContentAsBase64() {
        return contentAsBase64;
    }


    public void setContentAsBase64(byte[] value) {
        this.contentAsBase64 = value;
    }


    public String getFormat() {
        return format;
    }


    public void setFormat(String value) {
        this.format = value;
    }

}
```

Could this be the reason of the conflict ? I am also aware that to fix this I might have to write a custom XMLAdapter. But I am clueless about my next step since I am very new to this. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure you want to load/write the DataHandler object (bad idea)? Or is that annotation intended for the byte[] array in the next line? Anyway, your error source is that the ``DataHandler`` class doesn't have a default constructor and therefore cannot be instantiated by the XML framework.

Comment: I have changed the return type from DataHandler to byte[]. For now it has resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same Problem:
[JAXB / Java 11 / Tomcat - DataHandler No default constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61612982/jaxb-java-11-tomcat-datahandler-no-default-constructor)

You have two  "javax.activation" jars laoded from different Classloader, the DataHandler
outside of the JAXB classpath will have another hashcode, it will override the built in DataHandler from JAXB, doing this JAXB will try to instantiate DataHandler as a Pojo and will throw the Error: " No default constructor found on class",
search and remove the secound "javax.activation" jar, and the serialization will work again.